# C - possible reordering issue with pipe access and mutex

Tags: multithreading, pipe, mutex, instruction-reordering

I have 2 threads running after write_fd was initialized by a call to `pipe()`:

```
static bool finished = false;
```

*Thread 1*

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
if (!finished) {
    write(write_fd, buf, buf_len);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

*Thread 2*

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
finished = true;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
close(write_fd);
```

The question is whether it is possible for a compiler/cpu to reorder the instructions in Thread 2 in such a way that `close(write_fd)` is moved before the mutex?

If so, this might create a problem, as Thread 1 may write to a closed fd, or even worse, some other piece of code might be allocated the same fd, and Thread 1 would be writing to a wrong location.

This is a simplified form of what happens in my code. What can be done to make sure the `close` happens after unlocking in Thread 2, without actually moving the code into the mutex protected region? will calling the `close` through another function do it?

Comment: The code you have shown cannot produce the results you describe.   There must be something else going on.'

Comment: @TimRoberts what do you mean? are you saying the call to close can't be reordered? can you expand why not?

Comment: Yes.  The compiler can't reorder it because `finished` is a global and `close` is an external.  It cannot know whether reordering is safe.  The CPU can't reorder it because `pthread_mutex_[un]lock` does a memory barrier.